# Companies that provide SEO solutions?

Tags: seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to increase a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google)

I've seen a lot of those companies around, saying that they could improve my website's ranking in search engine results,

The thing is, that they say  you'll be on the first / second page, guaranteed.
I tried to contact a few of them, and they are charging a nice amount of money for it,
The cheapest I found was about 5,000$,

Now I didn't believe that they could make a huge change, but I did see that a few of their customers did get to the first pages fast, while leaving bigger and more experienced companies behind,

I'm quite sure that I could hear about their way of doing that, and maybe even do it myself.
So do you have any idea what those companies do to improve the ranking?

Comment: Hi Don, welcome to Webmasters.SE. It's hard to know specifically what question you're asking. Try rephrasing to get better answers from the community.

For tips on how to ask the right question, check out this page: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask

Cheers,
Ciaran

Comment: You've changed the question, but it's still not easy to answer specifically. If you look at the questions tagged SEO here you can find some of the tricks. The short answer to SEO is this though: produce good content for humans, not for search engines.